# Response.Write into <%If Else%> issue

Tags: html, vb.net, response.write

I've this code :

```
<td class="tr-inverse">
    <div>
        <%                                  
            If nbVetementsNonRendu <= 0 Then
               Response.Write(String.Format("<b>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</b>", nbVetementsNonRendu))
            Else
               Response.Write(String.Format("<span style='font-weight:bold; color:red'>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</span>", nbVetementsNonRendu))
            End If
        %>
   </div>
```

It's works pretty perfectly. My problem is the string is write two times : one before the head and one at the good cells.

We've found a solution to block the first writing :

```
<td class="tr-inverse">
    <div>
        <%                                  
            Response.Write(AffichageResult(dlDetail))
        %>
    </div>
</td>
```

and the vb.net code :

```
Public Function AffichageResult(ByVal dl As DataList) As String
    Dim retour As String = String.Empty
    indice = indice + 1
    If indice = 1 Then
       If nbVetementsNonRendu <= 0 Then
          retour = String.Format("<b>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</b>", nbVetementsNonRendu)
       Else
          retour = String.Format("<span style='font-weight:bold; color:red'>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</span>", nbVetementsNonRendu)
       End If
    End If
    Return retour
End Function
```

It's not really sexy... so there is a other way to fix this issue ? And why there is two writing ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've found this solution in VB code :

```
If nbVetementsNonRendu <= 0 Then
      resultnbVetNRendu = String.Format("<b>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</b>", nbVetementsNonRendu)
Else
      resultnbVetNRendu = String.Format("<span style='font-weight:bold; color:red'>{0} vêtement(s) en activité</span>", nbVetementsNonRendu)
End If
```

and in the html code :

```
<td class="tr-inverse">
    <div id="dVetNRendu" runat="server">
         <%=resultnbVetNRendu%>             
    </div>
</td>
```

and it works perfectly now but I can't understood the previous behavior... if someone has a explanation I'm interested !

Comment: Your first block of code (at the top), is it in a loop?  It is only one block, so I can't see another way that it would print twice.

Comment: Yes it's only one block. Even if my new code works correctly, I thought the = had the same value as the response.write and I am a little surprised that it has not the same behavior as before

Comment: Is there a `Response.Flush()` somewhere in the code?

Comment: @Keith no there haven't